# Extracting a regex from a set of strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of strings. I would like to extract a regular expression that matches all these strings. Further, it should match preferably only these and not many others.

Is there an existing python module that does this?

```
www.google.com
www.googlemail.com/hello/hey
www.google.com/hello/hey
```

Then, the extracted regex could be `www\.google(mail)?\.com(/hello/hey)?` 
(This also matches `www.googlemail.com` but I guess I need to live with it)

My motivation for this is in a machine learning setting. I would like to extract a regular expression that "best" represents all these strings.

I understand that regexes like 
`(www.google.com)|(www.googlemail.com/hello/hey)|(www.google.com/hello/hey)` or
`www.google(mail.com/hello/hey)|(.com)|(/hello/hey)` would be right given my specification, because they match no other urls other than the given ones. But such a regex will become very large if there are large number of strings in the set.

Comment: What would make you prefer your answer over www\.google(mail)?\.com.* ? Perhaps you need to explain what you're going to do with the regexp once you've found it in order to better define your question.

Comment: Maybe, you need this algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: @krilloid: That looks right! The answer I posted for my example was the one with the longest subsequence kept intact

Comment: @Phani, the longest common subsequence problem is NP-hard (i.e. computationally difficult), and this problem (finding the minimum regex) seems to be harder, so any algorithm that solves is likely to be slooooow. (EDIT: yes, it seems that it is: [reference](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/is-finding-the-minimum-regular-expression-an-np-complete-problem))

Comment: If the number of strings is not too large, then a disjunction of all of them would work well.

Comment: Unfortunately "too large" is not that unlikely: My python interpreter (2.7) will croak somewhere between 2500 and 3000 disjoined words from the dictionary. It will happily accept two parenthesized lists of 2500 (hence 5000 words), but not three of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little [perl library](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Regexp-Optimizer-0.15/lib/Regexp/Optimizer.pm) that was designed to do this. I know you're using python, but if it's a very large list of strings, you can fork off a perl subprocess now and then. (Or copy the algorithm if you're sufficiently motivated).